# Jmeter run test plan from command line with external link to properties

Tags: jmeter

**Problem:** In debug mode I can run test plan with no issues, but in none-gui got problem while parsing access to file, looks like properties file.
Here are details:

**jmeter.logs**
2018-08-31 13:26:30,831 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 2 must exist and be readable at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:424) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

**My Test Plan:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71PPB.png)
External property file contain link to other file with list of users.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktSVP.png)
Here is my Test Plan and property file reader sampler.

Both files SAT.properties, SAT.users.22315010.csv have full access

-rwxrwx---+ 1  Domain Users 212 Aug 31 12:41 SAT.properties

-rwxrwx---+ 1  Domain Users 123 Aug 30 13:20 SAT.users.22315010.csv

**Cmd command used to run script:**

jmeter -n -t D:\PW\Automation\Jmeter\Reports\Reports_Random.jmx -Jusers=1 -l D:\PW\Automation\Jmeter\Reports\Results\JResults.jtl

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in [Property File Reader](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/)  comments, you need to escape your path:

> If you want c:\abc , You need to have c:\abc as value in your property file as \ is used for escape sequence in Java

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using this "property file reader" makes sense as the functionality of reading an external properties file is available right out of the box in JMeter.

Instead of using the plugin you can just pass the path to your `SAT.properties` file using [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -q d:\PW\Automation\JMeter\Reports\Properties\SAT.properties -n -t D:\PW\Automation\Jmeter\Reports\Reports_Random.jmx -Jusers=1 -l D:\PW\Automation\Jmeter\Reports\Results\JResults.jtl
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I got same issue after disabling property file reader in GUI script and attempt to run same script from cmd with -q d:\PW\Automation\JMeter\Reports\Properties\SAT.properties.